# Sql Subselect ORA-00918

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my Sql:

```
SELECT 
    t.RUFNAME,
    count(v_anschrift.rufname) as Anrufe
FROM v_termin,
(
    SELECT 
    RUFNAME
    FROM
    V_Anschrift
    WHERE V_ANSCHRIFT.SPERRKZ = 0
    AND V_ANSCHRIFT.OEM != 0 
) t
JOIN v_anschrift ON (t.Rufname = v_anschrift.RUFNAME)
LEFT JOIN v_termin ON (v_termin.anschriftid = v_anschrift.anschriftid)
WHERE v_termin.TERMINART = 20
GROUP BY t.RUFNAME;
```

And i get this error message:

> ORA-00918: Spalte nicht eindeutig definiert
>   00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>   Fehler in Zeile: 15 Spalte: 7

where is my mistake?

Comment: Don't mix explicit and implicit joins. Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax everywhere! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: You have v_termin twice in the FROM clause. Intentionally? Have different table aliases.

Comment: Why are you joining twice to `v_anschrift`? and `v_termin`? The restriction on the `sperrkz` and `oem` can easily be added to the join condition. I don't see the reason to have a sub-select to begin with.

Comment: Simple: you have a `FROM v_termin` and then a `LEFT JOIN v_termin`, and you dont properly **alias** your tables, so Oracle can't tell from which table is the `v_termin.anschriftid =`. I begun to write a fix, but I stopped because your query is a mess, especially the subquery that has no ON CLAUSE.

Comment: Die you mean something like this: http://cryptb.in/L7rn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you actually want something like this:

```
SELECT t.RUFNAME, COUNT(*) as  Anrufe
FROM v_termin t JOIN
     v_anschrift a
     ON t.anschriftid = a.anschriftid
WHERE t.TERMINART = 20 AND
      a.SPERRKZ = 0 AND
      a.OEM <> 0 
GROUP BY t.RUFNAME;
```

You have repeated table references in the `FROM` clause -- and the repetitions have no obvious logic.